# best way to store salt key

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I currently develop web application using spring boot, i want to ask what is the best way to store salt key for encryption

Currently i create encryption util class and i still doubt about how to store salt key.

i have to 2 options : 
1. i create static final property on my encryption util
2. put at application.property file

or you have another suggestion

thanks

Comment: It seems this question was also asked at https://www.sslvpn.online/best-way-to-store-salt-key/

Comment: What is a "salt key"?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest is option 1 and it's IMO more secure than option 2 if you planned to put your key is in plain text in `application.properties`.

But the best would be to add your key in `application.properties` (option 2) and encrypt it, for example, with jasypt .

You can find samples with Spring boot [here](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot)